# Overloading operators using extension methods

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

I defined the addition between nullable int like this:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static int? operator +(int? value1, int? value2)
    {
        if (!value1.HasValue && !value2.HasValue)
            return null;

        int myValue1 = value1.HasValue ? value1.Value : 0;
        int myValue2 = value2.HasValue ? value1.Value : 0;

        return myValue1 + myValue2;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use this operator in .NET 3.5?
Is it possible in earlier versions of .NET?

PS.

Apparently actually there is no (?) way to **overload** operators using **extension** methods
because extension methods must be in static classes, and static classes can't have operator overloads....

PPS.

"Resolved" using

```
public static int? Add(this int? value1, int? value2)
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Yes, the code does not compile, the question is is it possible or not to build something like this.

Comment: If it won't compile, then you can't do it. Plus, you usually make operators inside custom classes, not as sudo-extension method for other existing data types.

Comment: Each error have associated error code. Try to read explanation/links i.e. in your case [CS0563](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zb1a95x1.aspx)? "...one parameter must be the same type as the class or struct that declares the operator..."

Comment: I need "null + 5 = 5"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# already "lifts" all operators onto nullable types.
If either operand is null, the operator will return null.

You don't need to (and cannot) do that.

Comment: The "either operand is null, the operator will return null" does not fit to my need... Is there a way to override this behavior? I need "null + 5" to be = 5

Comment: No, you can't.  And, the point of `null` in a nullable type is to represent an _unknown_ quantity.  An unknown quantity plus five is not five; it's also unknown.

Comment: You can write `(x ?? 0) + (y ?? 0)`.  Beware of precedence.

Comment: Apparently actually there is no (?) way to overload operators using extension methods because extension methods must be in static classes, and static classes can't have operator overloads.

Comment: C# does not support extension operators (the language team thought about that, and decided not to).  Therefore, you can only define operators involving your own types.

Comment: in my module, the "null" means *no value* (DBNull.Value), so, say, when I sum the nothing with 5 I need to obtain 5 (in my case is better for statistics than Null)

Comment: That isn't what `DBNull.Value` means.  Why not just use `0`?

Comment: because if I do an average of sold products will be sad if I obtain a null value just because one vendor of one thousand forgot to fill-in the data for its shop(DBNull.Value) - PS. 0 means that the vendor sold 0 products (didn't forgot to fill-in the data).

Comment: `(x ?? 0) + (y ?? 0)` gives 0 if both are NULL, I need NULL in that case. Thanks for your answer, I understood the idea! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloading permits user-defined operator implementations to be specified for operations where one or both of the operands are of a user-defined class or struct type.

The operator overloading you are trying to achieve does not involve any struct or any data type. Thats y your code doesnt compile.

You can find the reference for the same [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

You don't need to overload the operator instead use this

```
var result = value1.GetValueOrDefault() + value2.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Also, operator overloading is achieved within the scope of your `Type` i.e class or struct.

You can use an extension method like this

```
public static class Utils
    {
        public static int? Sum(this int? value1, int? value2)
        {
            if (!value1.HasValue && !value2.HasValue)
                return null;

            int myValue1 = value1.HasValue ? value1.Value : 0;
            int myValue2 = value2.HasValue ? value1.Value : 0;

            return myValue1 + myValue2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: extension methods can be used like Sum etc.

Comment: value1.GetValueOrDefault() + value2.GetValueOrDefault() gives 0 if both are null, I don't need this, I need null in that case...